# Partial View : Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: contentPath

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am implementing Partial View

Main View(Index) :

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Models.Employee>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 @Html.Partial("_Employee"  ,item)
}
```

Partial View(_Employeee.cshtml)

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Employee
<table style="font-family: Arial; border: 1px solid black; width: 300px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="@Url.Content(Model.Photo)" alt="Model.Alternate.Text"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Gender:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>@Model.Gender
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Salary:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>@Model.Salary
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On Runtime ..it give following Error ..

> Partial View : Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name:
>   contentPath

I have read 
[Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753326/problem-using-partial-view-in-for-each-loop) ..they suggested to implement

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MVCLD.Models.Employee>" %>
```

But how to implement in Razor View ...i dont know ..please Suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Url.Content(Model.Photo)
```

Does this property have a value? If not, you'll need to add some logic to check.

Comment: yes .. one Row in DB had incorrect Value ..Code is Fine ...Thanks